# Crystal Report not configured after installation?

Tags: c#, asp.net, crystal-reports

I have installed `VS 2010` - **32 bit** and also installed `Crystal Reports 2011` for **VS 2010**. What I did?

1. I have changed .NET Framework to 4
2. I have searched in properties general tab and also tried to add reference of Crystal Report Viewer but reference **not found**
3. Crystal Report adding shows `.mht` format not `.rpt`
4. I downloaded again from same url in mht but no change and Crystal Report not viewed
5. Error image (even after installation and changing to `.NET Framework 4`):

[image: IMAGE FOR ERROR CLICK HERE]

Answer (score 0):

download crytsal report for VS 2010 from this link no changes required after that

[CR SETUP 32bit for VS 2010](http://downloads.businessobjects.com/akdlm/cr4vs2010/CRforVS_13_0_12.exe) CLICK LINK